# Is there a way to get past this error using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd

I have a problem with my npm.I have this errors every time I run a command using NPM.I have tried reinstalling Node.js and npm  but the problem persists. What do you think the problem may be?
I have to mention that I am using windos 11.

Thank you.[image: npm errors]

Using any npm commands results this errors...I cant update npm to another version because its the same error when I run the command.

Comment: You can try these solutions https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874#issuecomment-663661148

Comment: Please use code instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these steps to fix the problem.

1. In your terminal, do `npm root -g`. It will give you a directory path.
2. `cd` to the directory listed by `npm root -g`
3. Delete the `npm` folder in the `node_modules` folder you `cd`-ed to.
4. Run `npm cache clean`